# Access control to the new user

Tags: jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

1. Create User

We could create user successfully by using  userManager.createUser

2. User Access privilege to absPath

created newSession  with newly created user.

```
String[] privileges = new String[]{PrivilegeConstants.JCR_ALL};
AccessControlUtils.addAccessControlEntry(newSession, absPath, new PrincipalImpl(user.getUsername()),
                        privileges, true);
```

Caused by: javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: No tree at /advitium/repo
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authorization.accesscontrol.AbstractAccessControlManager.getTree(AbstractAccessControlManager.java:164)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.accesscontrol.AccessControlManagerImpl.getApplicablePolicies(AccessControlManagerImpl.java:195)

whereas the same path can be accessed using admin session.

Question : How do we provide access to the node for the new user.

Comment: Resolved . We have to use admin session to assign prviliges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use admin session to assign prviliges with the newly created principal.